# Can't import modules in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth, pycharm, ebay-api

I'm following instructions and using files from: https://github.com/eBay/ebay-oauth-python-client

I'm getting error when I import: oauth2api, credentialutil, & model. This is step 3 in the above site.

```
import yaml, json
sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/kyle/PycharmProjects/app/ebay-oauth-python-client-master/oauthclient/model')
sys.path.insert(1, '/Users/kyle/PycharmProjects/app/ebay-oauth-python-client-master/test')
sys.path.insert(2, '/Users/kyle/PycharmProjects/app/ebay-oauth-python-client-master/oauthclient')
import credentialutil
import model
import oauth2api
print(sys.path)
```

error message:

C:\Users\kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe C:/Users/kyle/PycharmProjects/app/app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kyle/PycharmProjects/app/app.py", line 10, in 
    import credentialutil
  File "/Users/kyle/PycharmProjects/app/ebay-oauth-python-client-master/oauthclient\credentialutil.py", line 20, in 
    from model.model import environment, credentials
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model.model'; 'model' is not a package

Process finished with exit code 1

The code runs if I only import model:

```
import yaml, json
sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/kyle/PycharmProjects/app/ebay-oauth-python-client-master/oauthclient/model')
sys.path.insert(1, '/Users/kyle/PycharmProjects/app/ebay-oauth-python-client-master/test')
sys.path.insert(2, '/Users/kyle/PycharmProjects/app/ebay-oauth-python-client-master/oauthclient')
import model
print(sys.path)
```

no error message:

C:\Users\kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe C:/Users/kyle/PycharmProjects/app/app.py
['/Users/kyle/PycharmProjects/app/ebay-oauth-python-client-master/oauthclient/model', '/Users/kyle/PycharmProjects/app/ebay-oauth-python-client-master/test', '/Users/kyle/PycharmProjects/app/ebay-oauth-python-client-master/oauthclient', 'C:\Users\kyle\PycharmProjects\app', 'C:\Users\kyle\PycharmProjects\app', 'C:\Users\kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python38.zip', 'C:\Users\kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\DLLs', 'C:\Users\kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib', 'C:\Users\kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32', 'C:\Users\kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages', 'C:\Users\kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymodel']

Process finished with exit code 0

I'm also getting a green line under oauthclient, and I don't know why. Everything is spelled correctly.

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/kyle/PycharmProjects/app/ebay-oauth-python-client-master/oauthclient/model')
sys.path.insert(2, '/Users/kyle/PycharmProjects/app/ebay-oauth-python-client-master/oauthclient')
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see two problems.

First, it seems that you are using Python under Windows, but you tried to insert a MacOS path to `sys.path`. Are you sure that paths like `/Users/kyle/...` really exist in your file system?

Second, you only need to insert the parent path, i.e. `/path/to/ebay-oauth-python-client/oauthclient` to your `sys.path`. In my local test, this works:

```py
import yaml, json
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, r"C:\Users\guosh\Downloads\test\ebay-oauth-python-client\oauthclient")
import credentialutil
import model
import oauth2api
print(sys.path)
```

However, I would suggest you import the package as a whole, like below:

```python
import yaml, json
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, r"C:\Users\guosh\Downloads\test\ebay-oauth-python-client")
import oauthclient
print(sys.path)
```